# Date leap year validation regex

Tags: regex, date

I need a regex to validate date. Requires:<

1. format: yyyy/mm/dd (4 digits year, 2 digits month and day)
2. valid days and months (not allow 2014/13/32)
3. leap year validation

Here is my pattern:

```
^(\d{4})[\/](((0[1358]|1[02])[\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))|((0[4679]|11)[\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30))|(02[\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9])))$
```

I don't know how to check leap years.

Comment: Why use regex to validate dates in the first place?

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.  -- Jamie Zawinski.

Comment: it's easy to make a function to validate date. Regex is the wrong choice here.

Comment: I could see how this might be for an assignment, but how did I do?

Comment: it's seem impossible to check all leap years. Some people advice me to check from 1800 to 2096 year. I think it may work:

    ((18|19|20)[0-9]{2}[\/](0[13578]|1[02])[\/]31)|((18|19|20)[0-9]{2}[\/](01|0[3-9]|1[1-2])[\/](29|30))|((18|19|20)[0-9]{2}[\/](0[1-9]|1[0-2])[\/](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|((((18|19|20)(04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|2000)[\/](02)[\/]29)

Comment: 25cm Pass it to datetime.datetime.strptime like I did, and it will solve the problem of your leap years.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the sample for you:

```
^(?:\d{4}\/(?:(?:(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])\/(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]))|(?:(?:0[469]|11)\/(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30))|(?:02\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))))|(?:(?:\d{2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|(?:(?:[02468][048])|[13579][26])00)\/02\/29)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oG0dT9)**

Comment: I know the question required a 2 digits for month and day. However, if anyone is interested in accepting 1 digit as well, I have modified a little bit the regex above. 

With this one you will be able to verify dates like "2018/02/07" as well as "2018/2/7".

 | [See Regex & Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3PY3MHs-fS2gcPmq)

Comment: Can someone please help modify this to validate dates in the dd-mm-yyyy format?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use `re` combined with the `datetime` module:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('1999/12/2', '%Y/%m/%d')
datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 2, 0, 0)
```

So the function I'd use is:

```
def find_valid_dates(a_string):
    '''return a list of valid datetime objects from a string'''
    results = []
    for match in re.finditer(r'\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}', a_string):
        try:
            results.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y/%m/%d'))
        except ValueError as e:
            pass
    return results
```

To test:

```
txt = '''2014/12/31
2012/02/29
2014/01/31
No matches
2014/13/31
2014/12/32
2014/9/31
2014/4/31
2014/6/31
2014/11/31
'''

print find_valid_dates(txt)
```

prints:

```
[datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 31, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 31, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could simplify the regular expression as given below:

`^(?:\d{4}-(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01])|(?:0[469]|11)-(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)|02-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))|\d{2}(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])-02-29)`

Answer (score 0):

RegEx to check for valid dates following ISO 8601, SQL standard.

- Has a range from 1000-9999
- Checks for Invalid Dates
- Checks for valid leap year dates
- Format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
^([1-9]\d{3}[\-.](0[13578]|1[02])[\-.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d))|([1-9]\d{3}[\-.](0[469]|11)[\-.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30) ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d))|([1-9]\d{3}[\-.](02)[\-.](0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]) ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d))|(((([1-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[13579][26])00)))[\-.](02)[\-.]29 ([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d))$
```

- Can be easily changed to format: yyyy/mm/dd by replacing the "-" separator by "/" and removing `([01]\d|2[0123]):([012345]\d):([012345]\d)` for timestamp